# Problem with the connexion to the data base using Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc

I m setting up a CRUD application using a simple mySQL data base with the Spring MVC framework, but I am facing problems connecting to the DB.

I get the following error :

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

The last packet is sent successfully to the server. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Here is the code for the DAO :

```
package com.ApplicationDevis.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProjetDAO extends JpaRepository<Utilisateur, Integer> // entité à gerer et le type de l'ID 
{
}
```

for the entity :

```
@Entity 

public class Utilisateur
{
            @Id // pour dire que notre id et la cle primère
    @GeneratedValue // pour dire qu'elle est auto incrémenté 
    int id;


    String Nom;
    String Prenom;
    String Societe;

    String Ville;

    String CP;

    String Num_Tel;

    String email;
```

for my `application.properties` :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/BDD_Vanerum_Test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rida
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 

and finaly my pom.xml :

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: are you sure about the mysql connection string "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/BDD_Vanerum_Test" ? have you tried it with a different mysql client ? (the port may be 3306 which is the default mysql port, the 8080 port is probably your web app port)

Comment: Looks like mysql is not responding. Can you connect using same credentials from the terminal? Also You don't need `@Repository` annotation if you are extending the `JpaRepository`

Comment: @FouadHAMDI I  have tried both it gives me the same error. And "BDD_Vanerum_Test" is the name of a data base I have created from my terminal and it appears in "phpMyadmin"

Comment: Can you connect to the database from terminal?

Comment: @NikhilSahu While connecting from the Terminal I only put my password ( using the line : sudo mysql --password ) and it connects successfully, but I control my tables/Db using phpMyadmin.

Comment: Then you should use the default port as @FouadHAMDI wrote. `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BDD_Vanerum_Test`

Comment: @Rashin Yes I can acces to  tables and edit them.

Comment: @Rashin I did it gives the same error

Comment: On terminal `mysql -u root -p rida -P 3306 BDD_Vanerum_Test` should log you into mysql console. Then the query string mentioned by Rashin would work

Comment: you may eventually also try: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/BDD_Vanerum_Test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was just a JAVA version problem, I fixed it using  :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/BDD_Vanerum_Test?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

instead of the line I've used in the previous code.